# Getting EditText values from a different fragment

Tags: android, android-edittext, fragment

I have two fragments.  Fragment A and Fragment B.  Fragment A has an EditText view called EmpID.  Fragment B has a button called 'Submit'.  When I click the Submit button in Fragment B, I would like to retrieve the value entered in EmpID in Fragment A.  I'm trying do this using the following code, in OnClickListener for the button:

```
    EditText empID  = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.EmpID);
    String empIDStr = empID.getText().toString(); //I get null here
```

But I keep getting a null value even when I've entered data.  Can't I not get the value of an EditText view from another Fragment?  I'm sure I'm missing something here.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
Here's the logcat output:
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at ex.testApp.FragmentB$1.onClick(FragmentB.java:85)
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-23 12:32:13.883: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Here's FragmentB.java:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.FragmentB, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  final Button btnLeft = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnLeft);
  final Button btnRight = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnRight);
  buttonClick(btnLeft, btnRight);
}

private void buttonClick(final Button btnLeft, final Button btnRight) {
  btnLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

      if (btnLeft.getText().equals("Submit")) {
        EditText empID  = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.EmpID);
        String empIDStr = empID.getText().toString(); //I get null here
.....
```

Comment: The logcat would help us out even more.

Comment: Can we also see FragmentB.java?

Comment: it's getActivity().  Not getView() in 

    EditText empID  = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.EmpID);

Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem... i looked over that part too. =)

Answer (score 2):

I just set the variable to static and it worked.

```
private static EditText empID;
```

Comment: For the love of god, please don't use your views as static objects